# save a js value in a rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

On a rails 6 app, I have a form where I want to record a sound

I use a hidden filed `sound`

```
    <%= simple_form_for @lesson, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
        <%= f.input :title, label: false, placeholder: "Titre", autofocus: true %>
        <%= f.input :content, as: :text, input_html: {rows: "10"}, label: false, placeholder: "Enter a description"%>
        <%= f.hidden_field :sound, value: "nil", id: "sound" %> 

    <canvas class="visualizer" height="60px"></canvas>
      <div id="buttons">
        <button class="record">Enregistrer</button>
        <button class="stop">Stop</button>
      </div>
    <section class="sound-clips">

        <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary" %>   

<% end %>
```

In order to record my voice, I found some script here [MediaStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API/Using_the_MediaStream_Recording_API)
like so : https://mdn.github.io/web-dictaphone/

```
    const record = document.querySelector('.record');
    const stop = document.querySelector('.stop');
    const soundClips = document.querySelector('.sound-clips');
    const canvas = document.querySelector('.visualizer');
    const mainSection = document.querySelector('.main-controls');

    // disable stop button while not recording

    stop.disabled = true;

    // visualiser setup - create web audio api context and canvas

    let audioCtx;
    const canvasCtx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    //main block for doing the audio recording

    if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
      console.log('getUserMedia supported.');

      const constraints = { audio: true };
      let chunks = [];

      let onSuccess = function(stream) {
        const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

        visualize(stream);

        record.onclick = function() {
          mediaRecorder.start();
          console.log(mediaRecorder.state);
          console.log("recorder started");
          record.style.background = "red";

          stop.disabled = false;
          record.disabled = true;
        }

        stop.onclick = function() {
          mediaRecorder.stop();
          console.log(mediaRecorder.state);
          console.log("recorder stopped");
          record.style.background = "";
          record.style.color = "";
          // mediaRecorder.requestData();

          stop.disabled = true;
          record.disabled = false;
        }

        mediaRecorder.onstop = function(e) {
          console.log("data available after MediaRecorder.stop() called.");

          const clipName = prompt('Enter a name for your sound clip?','My unnamed clip');

          const clipContainer = document.createElement('article');
          const clipLabel = document.createElement('p');
          const audio = document.createElement('audio');
          const deleteButton = document.createElement('button');

          clipContainer.classList.add('clip');
          audio.setAttribute('controls', '');
          deleteButton.textContent = 'Delete';
          deleteButton.className = 'delete';

          if(clipName === null) {
            clipLabel.textContent = 'My unnamed clip';
          } else {
            clipLabel.textContent = clipName;
          }

          clipContainer.appendChild(audio);
          clipContainer.appendChild(clipLabel);
          clipContainer.appendChild(deleteButton);
          soundClips.appendChild(clipContainer);

          audio.controls = true;
          const blob = new Blob(chunks, { 'type' : 'audio/ogg; codecs=opus' });
          chunks = [];
          const audioURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          audio.src = audioURL;
          console.log("recorder stopped");

          deleteButton.onclick = function(e) {
            let evtTgt = e.target;
            evtTgt.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(evtTgt.parentNode);
          }

          clipLabel.onclick = function() {
            const existingName = clipLabel.textContent;
            const newClipName = prompt('Enter a new name for your sound clip?');
            if(newClipName === null) {
              clipLabel.textContent = existingName;
            } else {
              clipLabel.textContent = newClipName;
            }
          }
        }

        mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
          chunks.push(e.data);
        }
      }

      let onError = function(err) {
        console.log('The following error occured: ' + err);
      }

      navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(onSuccess, onError);

    } else {
       console.log('getUserMedia not supported on your browser!');
    }

    function visualize(stream) {
      if(!audioCtx) {
        audioCtx = new AudioContext();
      }

      const source = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);

      const analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser();
      analyser.fftSize = 2048;
      const bufferLength = analyser.frequencyBinCount;
      const dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);

      source.connect(analyser);
      //analyser.connect(audioCtx.destination);

      draw()

      function draw() {
        const WIDTH = canvas.width
        const HEIGHT = canvas.height;

        requestAnimationFrame(draw);

        analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(dataArray);

        canvasCtx.fillStyle = 'rgb(200, 200, 200)';
        canvasCtx.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        canvasCtx.lineWidth = 2;
        canvasCtx.strokeStyle = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)';

        canvasCtx.beginPath();

        let sliceWidth = WIDTH * 1.0 / bufferLength;
        let x = 0;


        for(let i = 0; i < bufferLength; i++) {

          let v = dataArray[i] / 128.0;
          let y = v * HEIGHT/2;

          if(i === 0) {
            canvasCtx.moveTo(x, y);
          } else {
            canvasCtx.lineTo(x, y);
          }

          x += sliceWidth;
        }

        canvasCtx.lineTo(canvas.width, canvas.height/2);
        canvasCtx.stroke();

      }
    }

    window.onresize = function() {
      canvas.width = mainSection.offsetWidth;
    }
```

And now I don't manage to save the sound I recorded as an object in my hidden field...

I tried this

```
function setHiddenValue() {
      // Get the value from the select tag
      var selectValue = $('select#lesson_sound_id').val();
      // Set the hidden tag's value to the select tag value we got in the last line
      $('input[type=hidden]#sound').val(selectValue);
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('select#lesson_sound_id').on('submit', setHiddenValue());
    }
```

Help would be very appreciated :p

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(selectValue)`? It looks like you might have an error with an extra `]` in the selector.

Comment: it says that the selectValue is undefined and yes there was an extra `]`i edited my code

Comment: If the console is showing an undefined value, then the element doesn't exist (try `console.log($('select#lesson_sound_id'))`) or the JS file that adds the sound objects isn't working properly. I didn't see a select in your HTML. I did see a `section` but it's missing a closure.

Answer (score 1):

Now I might be wrong here but IIRC `hidden` fields only accept string values. Assuming I'm right here, there's two options for you:

- use an `input type="file"` and simply hide it with CSS
- serialize your file into a base64 string and write that to the hidden field

I'd personally go with option 1.